# How do I parse the last 6 digits of a string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know how to parse the last 6 digits from a Java string. So:

```
String input1 = "b400" // the regex should return b400  
String input2 = "101010" // the regex should return 101010  
String input3 = "12345678" // the regex should return 345678
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No regex needed.

```
input.substring(Math.max(0, input.length() - 6));
```

If it has to be a regex for API reasons,

```
Pattern.compile(".{0,6}\\Z", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

If you need to match the last 6 codepoints (incl. supplementary codepoints), then you can replace `.` with `(?:[\\ud800-\\udbff][\\udc00-\\udfff]|.){0,6}`

Comment: I am not writing it from scratch. there is already written regex for this on which the entire program is built so i am looking for a regex specifically.

Comment: @Pan, in one of your examples, "b400 the regex should return b400" the result is shorter than 6 characters.  I simply decided to return the largest suffix that is 6 characters or less.  If you want the match to fail when the largest suffix is the empty string, then `{1,6}` is the way to do that.  If you always want exactly six characters, then `{6,6}` is the way to do that.

Comment: Tried the RegEx on a inputString and I have the sample am trying @ http://ideone.com/SVqoFQ, tghts??

Comment: @Sathish,   Try replacing `if (matcher != null)` with `if (matcher.find())`.  You're never actually calling `matcher.find()` so it never actually applies the regular expression to the string.  Java's regex library differs from some others in that you have a matcher, not a result object, and the matcher is non-null even before you do anything to generate any results.  Also, `Matcher.match` and `Matcher.find` are quite different so the API requires you to use one or the other instead of applying the pattern to the string when you create the matcher.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that for your example for "input1" you want just "400" (not "b400").  Here is a solution that will return up to the last six digits of the given string, or null if the string does not end with any digits:

```
public String getLastSixDigits(String source) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{0,6})$");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
  if (m.find()) {
    return m.group(1);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

As usual, store the pattern as a member to improve performance.

Comment: And this works because the regexp engine give you the biggest mathc.