# Regex expression to get the number out of the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like follows

```
            XXXX456
```

For example i sometimes get the string as

```
       <ignore>456
```

I want to get the number from this string

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218431/how-do-i-parse-the-last-6-digits-of-a-string-using-regex-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
yourStr = yourStr.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String s = "<ignore>456";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"([0-9]+)$"
```

Will match any number that's at the end.

Comment: What if you have a string like "123foo456bar" ?

Comment: Sorry, the dot was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<ignore>456");       
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```